# Train/validation split with a predefined mixture of target variable

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, train-test-split

I want to be able to make train/validation splits with a user-defined mixture of target variable. `StratifiedKFold` and `StratifiedShuffleSplit` from sklearn keep the mixture from the original sample. But on kaggle or in real life we often have a separate test sample that sometimes can have a very different target mixture.

Let's imagine that we have a binary classification problem at hand, but the labeled train sample has 50/50 mixture of 0/1 target vvalues, while the test does not have labels, but from one or another source we know that the proportion is rather 90/10. So the question is if there is a method in sklearn to get a split of the original sample with 90/10 mixture, where 90/10 would be an input argument.

It does not have to be a complete kfold CV split, but at least a cross-validation index generator ala StratifiedShuffleSplit

Comment: Doing 90/10 on a 50/50 dataset will lead to dropping of some training data. Are you willing to do that?

Comment: Yes, indeed, dropping some data might be unavoidable. At the moment I do not see an alternative, so at the moment i'm ready to pay this price.

Comment: For example, from 50:50 samples, you will have to choose 5 (or 6) samples of minority class, so that final ratio becomes 50/5 ~ 90/10.  Now the question becomes, choosing which ones:- Randomly only once, randomly until all the 50 samples of (soon to be) minority class are covered?

Comment: @VivekKumar I guess, the choice would be random- same as `StratifiedKFold` does (it does not differentiate on anything other than the target). And for the second question that you posted- either of the two would be fine. One can always consider to rerun with a different random seed

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that? I mean, when your data is imbalanced (like 90/10), you **really want** to do upsampling/downsampling (etc...) to re-balance it. The ratios of the test set have virtually no effect on the training set.

Comment: @QusaiAlothman could you please elaborate more on your point? I do not get it. Consider the example in the original question. Let's assume our evaluation metric is accuracy. So we optimise to get good reconstruction of both classes. However, maybe you just need to reconstruct well the 0-target class and you will get already 90% of all test examples right. In the binary example the two classes are self-excluding, so it it is not-0, then it is automatically 1. So this would be more relevant for a multi-class classification.

Comment: If it's that critical, why not just implement the CV generator yourself? just write a simple generator that yields train, test indices in the ratio you want. the sklearn implementation is nothing different.

Comment: @ShaharA fair point.There are two issues- 1) I have never dealt with CV generator writing in sklearn and my impression was that documentation of the base interfaces in sklearn is not very beginner-friendly. 2) This seems to be a very wide-spread situation, so I believed there would be (and I'm surprised there is no) a common implementation.